# Rails passing hidden form data via Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

UPDATE:  It seems like the error was probably due to a devise conflict.  I used some content from another app which apparently made devise go nutty and not be able to read user sessions.  I'll be starting with a clean install and seeing if I have better luck. Thanks!

I am creating a page which has a single question on it.  On that page I have a form where people can answer that question.  The form itself just has an answer block and a submit button.  However, I want to tie it to both the user submitting the form and the question the answer is linked to.  For security I want to do this in the controller, not the view.  The answer form is being shown on the questions#index page.  I am currently getting the following error:

```
undefined method `user' for #<AnswersController:0x007fe618e5cc10>
```

I suspect that if it made it past the user I would get the same for 'question'

The questions#index looks like this:

```
<div class="home_question">
    <h1><%= @daily.question %></h1>

    <div class="answer_form">
        <%= form_for @answer do |answer| %>
            <%= answer.label :answer, "What do you think?" %>
            <%= answer.text_area :answer %>

            <%= answer.button %>
        <% end %>

    </div>
</div>
```

The Questions Controller looks like this:

```
def index
    @daily = Question.find_by(show_month: Time.now.month, show_day: Time.now.day)
    @answer = Answer.new
end
```

The Answers Controller looks like this:

```
def index
  @answers = Answer.all
  @answer = Answer.new
end

def new
  @answer = Answer.new
end

def create
  @answer = Answer.new(answer_params)
  @user = user(params[:id])
  @question = question(params[:id])

  if @answer.save
    redirect_to root
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

def answer_params
  params.require(:answer).permit(:answer, :users_id, :questions_id)
end
```

The data currently being passed by the form is:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"mA16+dg7+Edzxvu/FVWR5r8PZ9zdNaOyvOwSz1VpOXU=",
 "answer"=>{"answer"=>"test"},
 "button"=>""}
```

Comment: what is `user(params[:id])` and `question(params[:id])` ??

Answer (score 2):

The error that you're getting is because in the controller you're using the `user` variable which isn't defined. You want to use the uppercase model name `User`.

**Getting the user id**

If this is a logged in user then you can get their id by looking in the session. Usually Rails application will have a helper like this:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

You don't need this helper if you're using devise -- it's already done for you.

**Getting the question id**

First make sure that your associated resources are nested. So in our `routes.rb` file:

```
resources :questions do
  resources :answers
end
```

This means that to create an answer we'll need to `POST /questions/:id/answers`.

The form changes to:

```
<%= form_for [@daily, @answer] do |answer| %>
  <%= answer.label :answer, "What do you think?" %>
  <%= answer.text_area :answer %>
  <%= answer.button %>
<% end %>
```

and in the controller:

```
def create
  @answer = Answer.new(answer_params)
  @answer.user = current_user
  @answer.question = Question.find(params[:id])

  if @answer.save
    redirect_to root
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for this!  It has gotten me one step closer.  It is passing the question ID but still isn't locating the user.  The error now says: 'ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in AnswersController#create
can't write unknown attribute 'user_id''.  I put the def current_user method in the AnswersController.  That was correct?  Thanks!

Comment: Question: how are you handling user login? Do users even log in?

Comment: Yes, everything is  being handled through devise.  At this point it is all open but once I get it functioning I will add restrictions so that users can only perform certain activities while logged in.

Comment: If you're using devise then `current_user` is already defined for you.

Comment: @Ahmed I guess there is no user_id attribute in answer. Don't need assign user_id to answer, assign question to answer is enough.

Comment: Yeah so he'll need to make a migration and do the user to answer association appropriately. I assumed that was done since he didn't show the models.